# MongoDB Query to get specific array element

Tags: arrays, mongodb, mongodb-query

I am new to MongoDB query. I have read some MongoDB books but unable to find way to query a document to check the value of a key. For example,

Document is:

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("57efaec42e656319d2a2860b"),
"Name" : {
    "First" : "Peter",
    "Last" : "John"
},
"Math" : {
    "SA1" : 10,
    "FA1" : 22,
    "Grade" : "A",
},
"English" : {
    "SA1" : 15,
    "FA1" : 25,
    "Grade" : "A-",
},
"Science" : {
    "SA1" : 18,
    "FA1" : 28,
    "Grade" : "A+",
},
"Subjects" : [ "English", "Math", "Science" ]
}
```

I want to Query: Is the Grade in Subject[0] == "A" ? It should return TRUE / FALSE. So it has to first find out the name of subject from the Subject Array and then use that name to compare Grade in that subject.

Answer (score 0):

This logic has to be written in the language which queries MongoDB. In SQL, we would probably write a statement which involves a sub query. But in MongoDB, it is advisable to write two seperate queries to achieve the result.

Sample function in JavaScript:

```
function checkIfStudentHasAGrade(){

var student = db.collection.findOne("_id":"<input _id>"); 

if(null != student){
var subject = student.subject[0];

if(student.subject.Grade == "A")
    return true;
else
    return false;
}
```

Comment: I am looking forward for a single MongoDB call either using aggregation pipeline or using $where or MapReduce.